# Should we exclude (or add) certain tags from the HNQ in order to prevent people from seeing spoilers?

Tags: feature-request

I understand that titles should be meaningful, and I admit that this just becomes a problem if something draws as much attention as its the case with GoT.

But still... I can't be quite sure as I haven't watched the season final yet, but I feel like the HNQ here just spoiled me with a compact summary of that episode.

> [image]

I came up with this a few times already, I know. And I'm aware of the options to just exclude the HNQs.

But still, not everyone is willing to dive into meta for solving his problem, and getting a HNQ-list as I just did, just hopping over the topics and its already too late to lookup any solution.

**My idea to solve this problem<sup>1</sup> in case this is technically doable, using a tag like [recent-release](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recent-release) and making that tag be negatively considered in the HNQ scoring so that each site could provide at most 1 post with that tag to the HNQ at a time, if not even banning it or giving its title a spoiler protection in the HNQ.**

EDIT: Note that this post actually mentioned from the very first beginning that hiding the HNQ is not considered a solution. Now just hopping back in here to see it was voted to be a duplicate of how to turn off the HNQ's feels a bit cheeky. Sorry for having to explicitly state this in an edit block. But having stated it in the text itself apparently got ignored.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>And it is a problem. Yeah each of the titles for them self isn't that spoily<sup>2</sup>, but HNQ as demonstrated makes that moot</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Well in my honest opinion, 3 of them are spoilers on their own</sub>

Comment: Argh. Titles which aren't spoilery in themselves but their *combination* is spoilery ... that's a tricky one, and well-nigh impossible to be sure of avoiding.

Comment: yeah, but I think at least the ways to avoid them could be improved. I tried to get to season 7 in time, but just started it yesterday and just from the HNQ titles over the last weeks, I had a few surprises, but the general plot developed exactly as I was expecting it. Its not that I want to blame someone, but I think this should somehow be improved.

Comment: Every question has every right to be in the HNQ, you're denying the right of a question to get the attention it deserves. The only reason this is a perceived issue is because people are **1:** Unable to be mature about spoilers. If you're on the internet expect to be spoiled. Our community serves the thousands, we can't make every individual happy. **2:** Because our site has what I call "Spoilerbility", content with the ability to spoil. Seeing something on a programming site beyond my knowledge is "cool". Seeing something on an SFF site beyond my knowledge is a "spoiler".

Comment: We have rules to hiding spoilers, and we try to make it as possible for everyone to be safe from them. In the case of some of these, titles are often overlooked as most of them are edited by users who have seen the episode, but we can't make it so that a random selection of HNQ questions in your sidebar doesn't spoil an episode for you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAQdc.jpg

Comment: @Valorum I'd say it's **not** a duplicate, since this is a proposal to exclude certain tags from the HNQs. Although I'm sure there's something on meta meta about that.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300350/239016

Comment: Oh dear, a spoiling title and a non-spoiling title, together, have spoiled your experience? This is already covered; the spoiling title, Starks figuring Littlefinger out, is already against current standards.

Comment: @Möoz: Why it is a duplicate? I clearly am supposing here a way to improve the handling, and not asking for assistance.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I'm fully aware of that, but I'm nto complaining, and isntead trying to propose a solution or getting feedback why its not solvable in a way like this.

Comment: @Zaibis I thought you were complaining? Wasn't the point of this a complaint that your episode got spoilt because two site were posting good content? We shouldn't deny a question the right to the HNQ and we should "limit" out sites exposure on the HNQ. If you're worried the HNQ will spoil you, go to the linked question.

Comment: [similar one from sister site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3970/is-it-justifiable-to-spoil-a-series-over-placing-a-title-too-off), answer might help here too

Comment: @AegonTargaryen I think it's the same user that asked these questions on both sites.

Comment: @NVZ I know, that's why I linked this one only and not any other one.

Comment: @AegonTargaryen: I feel like no one even reads the part after the picture. I even state there that its not a option for me to disable the HNQ and therefor would like to propose a feature, while this is also taged as feature request. and isntead people mark this as dup of my own posts or hint me that answers to posts I did may apply.

Comment: Because "recent-release" tag suggestion seems to do more damage then any help.

Comment: @AegonTargaryen: Then please put the why into an answer instead of assuming something that clearly isn't stated. As I don't see why that would be damaging.

Comment: @Zaibis post like this appear all the time with same spoiler complains , can't answer each of them every time.

Comment: @Zaibis and who is going to add  "recent-release" tag to every new question and then removing them after certain time? And how new is new?

Comment: @AegonTargaryen: Then you should simply write nothing instead of adding something you are aware of not being useful...

Comment: To the other part well dynamically adding/removing tags is a bit against the concept of tags. I was more thinking about the tag being relative to the date the post is being made. What also could be useful later as one could consider that by giving a answer that at the point the OP was made the asker had not the knowledge he might have now. And about how new is new. Well folks don't mind blaming me with "Oh cmon its so and so old already, how could that by spoily?" So I would propose a time frame of "so and so". I mean defining that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Don't know if you paying attention or not but your post bring nothing new on table and people get spoiler by 3/4 year old stuff too, we are already keeping title spoiler free, this tag idea seems too weird  to be even considered, implementing it will be the bad idea

Comment: @AegonTargaryen: Thanks for your thoughts, but I disagree. If you have anything further to add, please do so in form of a answer.

Comment: @Zaibis, we have a time frame for "so and so" it's never. Nothing is ever old enough to be a spoiler. Some things just enter common knowledge. I.e, "Luke I am your father", technically a spoiler, but not hidden because of how well it's known. Back to your point about disagreeing with the tags. Us as regulars of our Stack want our content (or sometimes not) on the HNQ because it draws attention to the stack, provides us with new users and provides rep (I guess). You denying our site space on the HNQ because we have content that is spoilery might be ok to you, but not to us.

Comment: @Edlothiad: then a previous meta post of me was wrongly answered. I was considering something from season 6 a spoiler and got shrug off by the statement howI can consider season 6 still as spoiler. I aggre then, that this solution wouldn't wokr out, but that based on a wrong previous statement.

Comment: Where's that meta and where's that answer? It's got an angry down vote coming it's way

Comment: @Edlothiad: Can't find it anymore. I remember it was related to this post https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167397/44517 And I don't know if it was answered on meta(I can't find that post anymore) or just a comment discussion then, but I complained about the title revealing the waifs death. And someone responded to that, that this is allready years old and how ridicoules it is considering that a spoiler.

Comment: By the way, why is this actually a duplicate? OP clearly mentions that turning HNQ off is not an acceptable goal. So why this is a duplicate of "Is there a way to turn off HNQ?" A bit rediciouless I must say...

Comment: @Zaibis - It's not a duplicate. It's a terrible idea, but it's not a dupe

Comment: @valorum Well thats not what I want to debate. Its just that this post was moderated inappropiate. Bad ideas arent forbidden on meta, are they? :p

Comment: @Zaibis - Bad ideas are extremely welcome. Downvoting them is one of life's simple pleasures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're proposing is a bad idea on multiple levels and extensively open to abuse.

1) This requires users to decide, presumably for themselves, what constitutes a "new release". You might wish to note that we've had complaints in the past about questions about *books* that were released decades ago spoiling TV shows and films including Lord of the Rings (1954) and 1984 (1948).

2) Even if we decide that it's a good idea, it still requires a technical solution from SE that they've been reluctant to perform. Blocking HNQ *by tag* has been [discussed previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224108/prevent-questions-with-movie-tv-shows-game-spoilers-from-appearing-in-the-hot-qu/257329#257329) on Meta:SE with the upshot being that while SE are happy to exclude entire sites, they're [not happy to exclude single tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308004/suggestion-remove-protected-questions-from-hot-network-questions-list/308022#308022) due to the costs involved and the network overhead.

3) Finally, and to my mind most critically, this gives users a brand new ability to knock any question they don't like off of the HNQ simply by adding a special tag. While we're usually *pretty quick* about noticing mis-tagging, it could theoretically be hours before that question gets edited back to normalcy during which time its 'hotness' may have declined.

Comment: It does absolutely nothing but replace *one* manual, subjective, user-driven task (editing spoilers out of titles) with *another* manual, subjective, user-driven task (adding a specific tag). Only that the proposed idea also doesn't help the site itself on top of that.

Comment: @TARS "It does absolutely nothing" That's nonsense. If you had read the OP, you would see that in that case it would make a major difference. But I accepted this answer for the 3rd point. As I had not considered that one back then. And I agree, that this would make in fact things difficult, even if there was a technical solution for it.